# Laravel 8 tymon/jwt-auth invalidate token to another user

Tags: jwt, token, laravel-8, soft-delete

I have a Laravel 8 API project using the [tymon/jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) package, and I'm trying to do the following.

1. As a user 'admin', I can delete others user's clients.
2. In the database, the entities are never deleted completely; I use a status attribute 'active'|'deleted' to soft-delete the entity.
3. After deleting a user, I need to invalidate the token if the user has one.

The problem comes with the last point, I can get the deleted user token, but I couldn't find how to invalidate that specific token in the JWT [docs](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/auth-guard/). I couldn't find a question like this either.

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $parameters = ['id' => $id, 'status' => 'deleted'];
    $user = request()->user();

    $data = User::where('id', '<>', $user->id)->where('status', 'active')
        ->where('id', $parameters['id'])->first();
    if (!isset($data)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'User does not exist'], 400);
    }

    $data->fill($parameters)->save();
    $token = auth()->tokenById($data->id);

    if ($token) {
        // TODO invalidate deleted user token
        // The next line invalidates the current auth token, not the target
        // user token auth()->invalidate($token);
    }

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Success'], 200);
}
```

If I properly delete the user from DB, the next requests using his token are now invalid because the user doesn't exist anymore. So there is a way to tell tymon/jwt-auth or the auth guard they need to check if the user has status = 'deleted'?

Answer (score 1):

You can invalidate token from middleware.

```
if ($user->blocked) {
      $token = $request->bearerToken();
      \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::setToken($token)->invalidate();
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invalidate any token if used `tymon/jwt-auth` package

```
$token = new \Tymon\JWTAuth\Token('bearer token.......');
\Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuthJWTAuth::manager()->invalidate($token, $forever = true);
```